# How to loop through a nested json data with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I already have a structure for my json file and what I would like to do is loop through the data and so I can style my HTML and have it print out output in this format.

The First Category>
   The First Video>
       linkto240p
       linkto360p
       linkto480p
       linkto720p

The Second Video>
       linkto240p
       linkto360p
       linkto480p
       linkto720p

Here is my data.json file and what I have done with the HTML file I have now.

```js
{
    "category": {
        "description": "The First Category",
        "subcategories": {
  
            "media": [{
                "durationFormattedMinSec": "1h 5m 37s",
                "files": [
                    {
                        "filesize": "230772320",
                        "label": "240p",
                        "progressiveDownloadURL": "linkto240p"
                    },
                    {
                        "filesize": "438519051",
                        "label": "360p",
                        "progressiveDownloadURL": "linkto360p"
                    },
                    {
                        "filesize": "594027617",
                        "label": "480p",
                        "progressiveDownloadURL": "linkto480p"
                    },
                    {
                        "filesize": "826531480",
                        "label": "720p",
                        "progressiveDownloadURL": "linkto720p"
                    }
                ],
                "title": "Our First Video"
            }]


   
   
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Our Video Download</title>
    
    <style>
        body{
            text-align: center;
            font-family: arial;
        }

        .button{
            margin:20px;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding:5px 10px;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Load the Videos" class="button" />
    <br />
    <span id="videos"></span>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.button').click(function(){

                $.ajax({
                    url: "data.json",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(data) {
     
                        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
      
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look up jquerys .each() method

Comment: @OlawaleAkinseye Can you check my answer. It has a working snippet.

Comment: JavaScript automatically parses JSON when the mimetype is application/JSON. Unless the data is n encoded (where n > 1) you don't need `var json = $.parseJSON(data);` If you have parts of the Response that is n encoded, you just need to loop n times and call  `var json = $.parseJSON(data);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
data = {
  "category": {
    "description": "The First Category",
    "subcategories": {
      "media": [
        {
          "durationFormattedMinSec": "1h 5m 37s",
          "files": [
            {
              "filesize": "230772320",
              "label": "240p",
              "progressiveDownloadURL": "linkto240p"
            },
            {
              "filesize": "438519051",
              "label": "360p",
              "progressiveDownloadURL": "linkto360p"
            },
            {
              "filesize": "594027617",
              "label": "480p",
              "progressiveDownloadURL": "linkto480p"
            },
            {
              "filesize": "826531480",
              "label": "720p",
              "progressiveDownloadURL": "linkto720p"
            }
          ],
          "title": "Our First Video"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').click(function(){
    // Do the AJAX stuff.
    $.each(data["category"]["subcategories"]["media"][0]["files"], function (i, v) {
      append = '<li>';
      append += '<p><strong>Size:</strong> ' + v["filesize"];
      append += '<p><strong>Label:</strong> ' + v["label"];
      append += '<p><strong>Link:</strong> ' + v["progressiveDownloadURL"];
      append += '</li>';
      $("ul").append(append);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: segoe ui; margin: 0;}
.button{
  margin:20px;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding:5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Load the Videos" class="button" />
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: This was not exactly what I wanted but it should gives me an idea what to try next and I really do appreciate you.

Answer (score 0):

I would say :

```
var listOfProgressiveDownloadURLs = [];
$.each(data.category.subcategories.media[0].files, function(index, file){
  var progressiveDownloadURL = file.progressiveDownloadURL;
  listOfProgressiveDownloadURLs.push(progressiveDownloadURL);
});

console.log('listOfProgressiveDownloadURLs:', listOfProgressiveDownloadURLs);
```

Comment: This answer does not work and I am getting an undefined message.